# Raster image wrapping/transformation in C++

Tags: c++, image, transform, gdal

I need to transform a raster image in C++ using some method. Like polynomial transformation, Delaunay triangulation and then Affine for each triangle, or any other method really.
So, on the input we have an image, list of source coordinates, and the list of target coordinates to which the source ones should be transformed. And thus I want to get warped image on the output.

To do so I'd like to use a c++ library. Any recommendations?

I'm looking toward GDAL and it seems that it's capable to perform the transformation. But I'm a little bit confused because there are a lot of terminology about coordinate system transformation. Is it suits for me?

Comment: I'd check out OpenCV

Comment: I've found delaunay triangulation in geos lib. Pretty easy to use. Now it would be perfect to find affine transformation somewhere.